# Change value in cell based on partial string match from list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that looks similar to the image below:

[image]

I am trying to find a macro that will compare the description in column C to the list in column F.

If a match is found like in row 3, I would like a "1" to be added to cell D3.
If a partial match is found like in row 11, I would like the same result in cell D11.

Does anyone know how to loop through the C column and add data to the D column based on the list in the F column?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Loading data into an array to improve efficiency

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [InStr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008946)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arrData, arrDataF, rngData As Range, rngDataF As Range
    Set rngData = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").CurrentRegion
    Set rngDataF = ActiveSheet.Range("F2").CurrentRegion
    arrData = rngData.Value
    arrDataF = rngDataF.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 3) = 0
        For j = LBound(arrDataF) + 1 To UBound(arrDataF)
            If InStr(1, arrData(i, 2), arrDataF(j, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                arrData(i, 3) = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ...

[image: Result]

Formula = `=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND($E$2:$E$5,B2)),0,1))`